# clear cache on rennokki eloquent-query-cache

Tags: laravel, caching, eloquent

Hello I'm using laravel with rennokki's eloquent-query-cache I could cache queries and it works perfectly but i need my cache gone when user logs out.

I tried `model::flushQueryCache();` in the logout controller but it doesn't work.

thank you.

Comment: Can you describe more what makes you say that it doesn't work?

Comment: I'm still getting outdated data

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work like that. How many models have your application? You should import the trait and write the `model::flushQueryCache();` for each model you have on logout event.

**If you want it more simple**, execute `Artisan::call('cache:clear')` on logout. This will clear everything, but for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

hmrneves thanks for your answer,

```
    public function logout() {
        admins::flushQueryCache();
        invitations::flushQueryCache();
        customers::flushQueryCache();
        rides::flushQueryCache();
        users::flushQueryCache();
    }
```

I tried this and imported the trait, it doesn't work. and I need to keep cache for other users

Comment: It caches by model not user.